# Google data studio make a copy of report but use another dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

Currently I use Data studio to visualize data that come from BigQuery. Let say I have created two data sources "tbl_user" and "tbl_product" and created some charts based on them. Both data sources come from one BigQuery dataset (let say "my_project.dev").

Now I have to bring the report to prod, so I use "Make a copy". But it's actually no option for me to specify the dataset. I want it to copy the whole things (data sources, blends, charts, etc), but let me control which dataset that the cloned data sources based on (let say the dataset is "my_project.prod").

So my question is, is there any way to archive my requirement? Or I must edit every cloned data sources and change the dataset manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible the Linked API may resolve your problem: https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/integrate/linking-api

You can set the ***ds.ds0.datasourceName*** and over options, like tableId, dataset, etc.

```
https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/create?
c.reportId=7890
&r.reportName=MyNewReportWithMultipleDataSources
&ds.ds0.datasourceName=MyNewDataSource
&ds.ds0.connector=bigQuery
&ds.ds0.type=TABLE
&ds.ds0.projectId=bigquery-public-data
&ds.ds0.datasetId=samples
&ds.ds0.tableId=shakespeare
&ds.ds1.viewId=92320289
```

So, deployment will be like click on prepared link. If you will be success with it, please tell about your experience. I Am in solving of same issue.